# Django Admin: Why are some fields showing up empty?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-fixtures

I have a Django blog with a "Post" model like so:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
         ('breakfast','Breakfast'),
         ('brunch','Brunch'),
         ...
    )
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
```

I have uploaded a bunch of "Post" objects (with all of the above fields completed) to my database using the `python manage.py loaddata fixturename.json` command.  However, when I log into the admin site to modify the objects, the values I uploaded for the "category" field do not show up as pre-selected in the field's drop-down list.  Why is this?  And is there any way to fix it?

EDIT: Here is snippet from my json fixture file:

```
    {
    "pk": 34, 
    "model": "blogs.post", 
    "fields": {
        "category": "breakfast",  
        "author": "jennaboller", 
        "text": "I have to say, my favorite weekend breakfast is blah blah blah", 
        "title": "Corned Beef Hash & Eggs: My Favorite Weekend Breakfast", 
        "pub_date": "2011-01-25 05:05:37"
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the data in the category field corresponds to the raw values, ie the first element in each CHOICES tuple? What do you see when you get a Post instance in the shell and do `print post.category`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, if I use `print` I get `breakfast`.  If I just use `post.category` I get `u'breakfast'`.  But I've already tried changing the CHOICES tupple to unicode values and it didn't help.

Comment: Can you show us an excerpt, i.e. a single `Post` object instance from your `fixturename.json`? Otherwise, I'm afraid it's difficult to help you. However, your issue might be related to the attribute `blank=True` in the `category` field. Also, what does your `PostAdmin` admin config class look like?

Comment: @PeterStahl, I edited my post to show a piece of my JSON file.  My PostAdmin config class subclasses `admin.ModelAdmin` and is just two lines, `inlines=[PostImageInline]` and `Media=CommonMedia`.  The first references a class that subclasses `admin.TabularInline` and the other `CommonMedia` is just a class with a js file tuple and a css file dictionary.

Comment: Mhm...nothing peculiar about your JSON data. Can you remove the attribute `blank=True` from the `category` field and test it again? This is my only idea for now, unfortunately...

Comment: @PeterStahl, I think this might have been the solution--I removed the `blank=True` attribute and the `category` field is now pre-selected!  Do you want to post an actual answer so I can give you the green checkmark?

Answer (score 1):

According to what I said in my last comment to the question, this issue is most probably related to the attribute `blank=True` in the `category` field of the `Post` model. But since you specified a particular category for your example model instance (*breakfast*), it should show up in the admin configuration as well.

The reason for this behaviour might be that Django doesn't expect the `blank` attribute in a `CharField` that has set the `choices` attribute because it doesn't really make sense here. If you want to be able to say that a `Post` instance doesn't belong to a particular category, then it's probably better to include another option in the `CATEGORY_CHOICES` such as `('none', 'None')`. Maybe this could also be a bug in Django's admin module, but I don't know about this.